# Start Cocoa app without showing the main window

Tags: cocoa, nsapplication, mainwindow

I have a simple Cocoa app with a single NSWindow where I can enter some credentials and after the submission the app starts an another process. In case the credentials were entered once and cached I would like to start the process by running the app without showing the app's main window. How can I achieve that?

The app has only one class that conforms to NSApplicationDelegate and one .xib file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is your window created from a xib file? There should be a "Visible at launch" checkbox in the properties for the window.

You'll need some other UI (such as a menu item) to start your work going — or you could put that in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

Comment: Do you know how can I set that programmatically? Until credentials are not cached I need to display it.

Comment: I found, its easy: [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self] when I need it.

Answer (score 2):

In your MainMenu.xib file, select the window and uncheck "Visible at launch". I believe this is all you need to do.

Comment: Do you know how can I set that programmatically? Until credentials are not cached I need to display it.